# I have 10 buttons that I want when I press a button, a function occurs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with 10 buttons I want when I press a button the speech inside it changes
And div appears, and when you click the second time, everything returns as it was

button 10 html

```
<button class="button" id="movetool">click 1</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool2">click 2</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool3">click 3</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool4">click 4</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool5">click 5</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool6">click 6</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool7">click 7</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool8">click 8</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool9">click 9</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool0">click 10</button>
```

button javacsript

```
var activeButton = localStorage.getItem('activeButton');
var isActive = localStorage.getItem('isActive');
const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

[...allButtons].forEach(function(thisButton) {
  if (isActive === 'true') {
    if (activeButton !== thisButton.id) {
      thisButton.disabled = true;

    }
  }
});

const movetool = event => {
  activeButton = localStorage.getItem('activeButton');
  const target = event.target.closest("button");
  if (activeButton === target.id) {
    var enableAll = false;
    Array.from(allButtons).forEach(function(thisButton) {
      if (thisButton.disabled) {
        enableAll = true;
        return;
      }
    });

    if (enableAll) {
      Array.from(allButtons).forEach(function(thisButton) {
        thisButton.disabled = false;
      });

      localStorage.setItem('isActive', false);

    } else {
      Array.from(allButtons).forEach(function(thisButton) {
        thisButton.disabled = true;
      });
      if (target.classList.contains("button")) {
        target.disabled = false;
        localStorage.setItem('isActive', true);
        localStorage.setItem('activeButton', target.id);
      }
    }
  } else {
    Array.from(allButtons).forEach(function(thisButton) {
      thisButton.disabled = true;
    });
    if (target.classList.contains("button")) {
      target.disabled = false;
      localStorage.setItem('isActive', true);
      localStorage.setItem('activeButton', target.id);
    }
  }
}
document.querySelector('.button_container').addEventListener('click', movetool);
```

I want to change the text when I press the button to "clicked"
and show div

code

the button is clicked

Comment: Can you describe the problem that you encountered with this code?

Comment: The symbol works, but I want when I press the button the name of the button change

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```js
allButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  localStorage.setItem('isActive', button.id)
  
  // Do that refresh loop you had at the top of your question
})
```

Comment: And I want to change the text and add a div

Answer (score 0):

Inside your moveTool event listener callback

```
thisButton.innerHTML = 'clicked';
```

Comment: where Inside your moveTool event listener callback

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is doing and why it's saving to local storage.
You should try and split it into smaller functions.
When you have decided a button has been clicked or is at a clicked state, apply that code.